# AG Grid, Capture the event on click of chevron

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

[image: screenshot of ag-grid nested with chevron]

Ag-grid provides `onCellClicked` event for when a cell is clicked. But I noticed that it doesn't trigger when we click the chevron. I need to capture this event for analytics as a user might click the chevron directly rather than the cell itself. Any idea how to achieve this or what event to use here? I am using `detailRenderer` to render child rows, if that helps. Here is one of the `columnDefs` item:

```
{
      headerName: "Line Item",
      field: "displayLineNumber",
      width: "100px",
      sortable: false,
      expandable: true,
      onCellClicked: (event) => {
        event.node.setExpanded(!event.node.expanded);
        if (event.node.expanded === true) {
          DataLayerUtils.pushEvent(
            "click",
            {
              name: "Open Line Item",
              type: "button",
            },
            {
              click: {
                category: "Quote Detail Table Interactions",
              },
            }
          );
        } else {
          DataLayerUtils.pushEvent(
            "click",
            {
              name: "Collapse Line Item",
              type: "button",
            },
            {
              click: {
                category: "Quote Detail Table Interactions",
              },
            }
          );
        }
      },
      rowClass: ({ node, data }) => {
        return `cmp-product-lines-grid__row ${
          !data?.children || data.children.length === 0
            ? "cmp-product-lines-grid__row--notExpandable"
            : ""
        }`;
      },
      detailRenderer: ({ data }) => (
        <section className="cmp-product-lines-grid__row cmp-product-lines-grid__row--expanded">
          <ProductLinesChildGrid
            gridProps={gridProps}
            license={gridProps.agGridLicenseKey}
            columnDefiniton={
              whiteLabelMode ? whiteLabelCols() : quoteDetailsCols()
            }
            data={data.children}
            onModelUpdateFinished={() => {
              markupChanged(mutableGridData);
            }}
          />
        </section>
      ),
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two ways to achieve this:

1. Implement the Grid Event `rowGroupOpened` (see: https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/grid-events/#reference-rowGrouping-rowGroupOpened)

This will be triggered whenever the user opens a group node.

```
onRowGroupOpened={(params) =>
  console.log('onRowGroupOpened', params.expanded)
}
```

2. Implement the Grid Event `cellMouseDown` (see: https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/grid-events/#reference-selection-cellMouseDown) to capture the chevron click event.

This will be triggered only when the user clicks the expand chevron

```
onCellMouseDown={(params) => {
  const isMasterRowGroupExpanded = params.event.target.classList.contains(
                'ag-icon-tree-closed'
              );
  if (isMasterRowGroupExpanded) {
    console.log('onCellMouseDown', params.value);
  }
}}
```

See both of these approaches implemented in the [following plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/4sQdiBTwddTESlbI).

Comment: I have `expand all` and `collapse all`. Do you think this will interfere when those events are fired? I'll certainly give this a try and accept your answer if it works. Thank you and really appreciate this.